# Why do many sites leave half of each webpage empty?

Tags: website-design, design, white-space

Why do many sites leave half of each webpage empty? Isn't this a waste of screen space?

One nice example of this is the Stack Exchange Network sites:

[image: Screenshot of UX Stack Exchange with annotations]

As you can see, there is a ton of whitespace left on both sides of each page.

Does the whitespace make sites compatible with certain screen sizes?
Does leaving the space help make sites mobile friendly?
Does space make pages seem less crowded, and thus, more usable?
Or, is there no good reason and people just do it because they don't realize they shouldn't?

I've worked on sites that use both designs and haven't had users complain either way.

Examples of sites that have space: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [GitHub](https://github.com/), [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/)
Examples of sites without space: [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/), [Chase](https://www.chase.com/), [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53309/discussion-on-question-by-tot-zam-why-do-many-sites-leave-half-of-each-webpage-e).

Comment: Because no one wants to read a 27-inch-long line of copy.

Comment: I'm not sure about your Google Search example.  The one you included has an additional element that fills in the space.  [A different query](https://www.google.com/search?q=Tot+Zam) could be made that leaves empty space.

Comment: @DavidStarkey You are not the first to mention something with that example, so I replaced it with Gmail.

Comment: Amazon, Chase, and Linked in all use space - maybe you need a bigger monitor...

Comment: @BradWerth My monitor screen is wide enough. Those sites do not have huge empty gap on the sides, at least not on the pages I was looking at.

Comment: They do on the links that you posted... maybe the pages you were looking at would have made better link targets.

Comment: Make note that you're comparing an application (Gmail) with informational websites. Applications meant to perform functions operate under a somewhat different criteria from applications meant to present text information. Somewhat like comparing the UI of Word to that of Photoshop. Also note that once opening an email to read in gmail, there is empty whitespace on the side.

Comment: @MartinBean, Some of us do want that space used (e.g. on Stack Exchange I have a user script that changes it such that the space is used). Allowing the user to define the space used is part of what having *windows* is all about. By not adapting to what the *user has selected* for a width (by resizing the browser window), the site is usurping user agency. It can imply arrogance on the part of the web sites' designers' that they *know* better what the user wants than the user. Note: that this applies to both wide and narrow views.

Comment: @Makyen If you take issue with Stack Exchange using fixed-width containers and see it as an attack on your proficiency to use a computer, then browsing the Internet is going to be a very woeful experience for you indeed.

Comment: As a sidenote, many websites look much better on HD screens when you rotate those screens to portrait position.

Comment: They're not empty, they're full of comfort space, to ease visualization.

Comment: The last guess, *"people just do it because they don't realize they shouldn't?"* can't be right, because you have to take some action to specify a margin like that.  I suspect the reason is that the authors believe their users to be incapable of resizing a browser to a comfortable width.  Many authors seem to have a misconception about text size, too.

Comment: Could you be clearer what you mean by "both designs" in your penultimate paragraph?  You've only described one design above it.

Comment: this is the reason I use all my screens in vertical mode (a.k.a. portrait mode). The thing is that it was movies and games that made the 16:9 format popular, *not* websites.

Comment: Your screen's logical DPI is set incorrectly. :-)

Comment: all about the saccades

Comment: This can't be fully serious, can it?

Comment: Whitespace **is not** wasted space, it's an important element in typography and design. See here: http://www.seguetech.com/whitespace-web-design/

Comment: `...because they don't realize they shouldn't?` Huh?? There's the problem, a false assumption.

Comment: Hehe, [do they](http://i.imgur.com/A3nFzh5.png)? :-P

Comment: FWIW Facebook's messenger.com is full width and I find it very hard to read when the window width reaches about 1000px.

Comment: Interesting that your _Examples of sites without space_ is the same as my _sites that make my eyes bleed_ list.

Comment: [It is "Stack Exchange", not "StackExchange"](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance). (the last section, "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"). And "Stack Overflow", not "StackOverflow" . Please edit your question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I didn't know that. Thanks. I updated the question.

Comment: They don't. You made your window wider than the website.

Comment: @Makyen Link to userscript ? I'd like to try it.

Comment: As a user with a large monitor, I never have my browser at full-screen. Because I don't want to have to pan my view left and right to look at the whole web page. Most sites restrict their page width to a maximum for the same reason.

Comment: @Simba If you look at [Makyen's comment](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/why-do-many-sites-leave-half-of-each-webpage-empty?noredirect=1#comment168674_104705), apparently some users feel that sites should not restrict the size of the page and let users handle that with resizing their own windows.

Comment: because they are designed for small screens. see http://alistapart.com/article/surveying-the-big-screen

Comment: I always assumed that those "empty" spaces were thanks to my adblock. :D hahahaha

Comment: It's because we have developer tools open all the time!

Comment: @noah1989 I personally like the developer tools on the bottom of the browser, not the side, so that wouldn't be the case for me.

Comment: Beautiful https://userstyles.org/styles/172637/stackoverflow-simply-wide

Answer (score 140, accepted):

There are many reasons, but the main ones are **visual cluttering** and **hierarchy of information** on one side, and **structural consistency** on the UI side.

## Visual Cluttering

> Clutter is an important phenomenon in our lives, and an important
>   consideration in the design of user interfaces and information
>   visualizations. Many existing visualization systems are designed to
>   reduce clutter by filtering what objects or information the user sees,
>   or using non-linear magnification techniques so that objects in the
>   center of the screen are allowed more display area. Tips for designing
>   web pages, maps, and other visualizations often focus on techniques
>   for displaying a large amount of information while keeping clutter to
>   a minimum through careful choices of representation and organization
>   of that information. [Rosenholtz et al., 2005]

Simply put: the idea is to avoid visual and therefore cognitive overload by presenting elements in a logical way. This logical way is related to the next point:

## Hierarchy of Information

Information has a hierarchy, and it's the most important part of what you want to show. Namely, the difference between failure and success.

> The hierarchy of information is a universal design principle that
>   should be used in all forms of design, including e-Learning design. By
>   definition, it is the arrangement of elements or content on a
>   page/screen in such a way that it reveals an order of importance
>   (either ascending or descending).

Take a look at the *boxed* model below:

[image]

As you may see, it's quite clear that the hierarchy is structured and understandable by most people. Please note that in responsive mode this hierarchy will stack all the elements as expected, so the *mobile advantage* is very clear

Now, the same layout, transformed to full-width:

[image]
*(try seeing it full size)*

Now, hierarchy 1 has gone, and user's eye will probably scan 2 and 3 first. And then 6 and 7! Basically, our most important element is down below the hierarchy. We can change it so the order is something like 3-1-2-4. Then we'll also have issues when stacking on responsive models (not only devices, even screen resizing), because 3 will be the first element, so again, we're creating issues rather than solving problems.

As you can see, the issues are quite big, and these are just the main ones.

But then we also have the UI or layout side:

## Structural Consistency

Let's say you have a full width page. No matter what, it will be 100%. 100% for the person on a small laptop and 100% on a 24 inches monitor. It's easy to see that the person on a laptop will see condensed information, with a certain structure that will show elements in a very specific way with a very specific amount of information in the screen.

Now, the user on that 24 inches monitor will see something extremely different. First of all, chances are the user will feel as in a *tennis match*, with her head going from one side to the other. **Visual saturation and friction will be incredibly high**, of course. But **the vertical display of information will be different as well.** See below:

**1366x768**
[image]

Now **1920x1200** (24 inches monitor)
[image]

Quite a difference, huh? Images have been enlarged *(and this could be yet another issue!)* and text kept his size, almost doubling the amount of text. Now think on this multiplied by the incredible amount of screen sizes that exist, and those that still don't exist and will maybe show up in the next months

In other words: **instead of preserving control, we're giving it up in favor of randomness**.

Of course, we're talking of general rules, not extremely specific cases, so there will be exceptions here and there

## One final note:

I want to make clear that from your examples with full width, only Amazon uses it, and it took them years of testing (there was a very interesting article about this I can't find right now) with countless A/B tests. But here you have hierarchy working: they're selling products where they can't know hierarchy before hand since most products will hold a similar approximated *weight*  , so you'll do your best to match user's search.

As for Google, they use a *boxed* model and align content to the left with a small gap of white space on the left. LinkedIn main pages are *boxed and centered*, although it's true the landing page for non logged in users has a full width element. But if you pay close attention, everything else is *boxed*, even on that page

Comment: 1+ @Devin Very informative and comprehensive answer. Keep up the good work!

Comment: I might be mistaken, but even Amazon doesn't use full-width. or at least,  they don't fill the page with 100% content, there still can be found quite some white space. https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=scene+switch

Comment: @Rvervuurt, that's why I mention they're constantly testing. For example, I have a quite big monitor. When I clicked your link on Firefox, it gave me a boxed, centered layout. After I logged in, I got a page with around 90% of space used, aligned to the left. On Safari, logged off, I got a 100% width. This kind of *inconsistency* (so to speak) is typical of Amazon, but most pages out of results page are usually at 100%, no matter if logged in or out. Results pages are quite random

Comment: I disagree that we are giving up control, and I disagree that the result is randomness, when we do not attempt to constrain the outer bounds of the content. We are acknowledging our lack of control over the user's greater workspace layout, and affirming the user's prerogative in organizing that, using tools that all users either have, or don't need. The result is not random, or even arbitrary. The result, is the layout that the user believes is best suited for their task at hand, in which your product *may be a small, insignificant part* despite it's overall potential.

Comment: Just to throw in my 2cents, full width is super tricky to pull off without it looking like mess, nobody wants to read such a long line and most of text would fall into single line which is not great, also in my case, only <2% uses screen resolution so big that empty space on sides is noticeable.

Comment: Now in 2023, amazon does not use full width. They have a max of 4 tiles across a max width of 1460px, and space either side.

Answer (score 86):

> The optimal line length for your body text is considered to be 50-60 characters per line, including spaces (“Typographie”, E. Ruder). Other sources suggest that up to 75 characters is acceptable.

[source](https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability)

Keeping a website clean (and simplistic) is a design trend, but it also has usability values. There is less noise and users can find stuff more easily.

But adding a max width to your content is primarily good for readability. Just take a look at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/) and you'll notice why line length matters.

Comment: Although [this is true](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34120), I think the question behind is why not fill the empty space with other elements.

Comment: Yes, like @Alvaro says, I agree that main content should stay in the middle, yet I don't see why navigation and ads aren't moved to the side.

Comment: Many people (I'm one) still use the 768 x 1024 form factor, whether because they prefer it, or they don't want to discard a perfectly good monitor, or they don't have the money to buy a decent widescreen.  The sites that *do* spread their stuff out such that a widescreen monitor is required are sites that don't get a lot of traffic, I'd bet (how many people are willing to scroll back and forth?)

Comment: @MMacD Sites can be made responsive though and use as much space as possible, and get smaller if the screen is smaller.

Comment: @TotZam Perhaps there are no more page elements to fill the space. Perhaps because it just doesn't look good. [Keeping stuff above the fold so it will be noticed isn't that important](http://www.hugeinc.com/ideas/perspective/everybody-scrolls) (anymore).

Comment: @PaulvandenDool Like I mentioned [here](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/104705/why-do-many-sites-leave-half-of-each-webpage-empty/104710?noredirect=1#comment168484_104708), I thought of this question when looking at the discussion regarding the new SO top-bar design, and they definitely have enough content to fill the space.

Comment: @TotZam I here on SE a logo, five links and a button. It fits on the same width as the rest of the container. I see no need to push those items all the way to the side.

Comment: @PaulvandenDool Not if you are trying to consolidate the two top bars like they currently are trying to do on SO. And the top-bar is what triggered the question, but my question is really regarding all the content on a page.

Comment: @Tot Zam: But the resolution of the display is only an upper limit on the pixel size of the browser window.  For instance on a 1920x1200 display, the browser window is about 1000 pixels wide.

Comment: See guidelines for measure at The Elements of Typographic Style Applied to the Web: http://webtypography.net/2.1.2.

Comment: I'm intrigued by your last comment, about reddit. Are you saying that it is unreadable? Actually here's an even better example: [danluu.com](https://danluu.com) which has barely any CSS, so all text occupies the whole screen. (The most recent page is actually quite relevant: [web-bloat](https://danluu.com/web-bloat/).) I really appreciate being able to read text like that, and I'm wondering whether this claim (that text becomes hard to read after some number of characters) is really valid.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR it's all about the fact that when the line gets to wide, your eyes will lose track of where the line you're reading started (peripheral vision). Therefor it's also hard to know where the next line starts. It's frustrating and tiring on the eyes to search for that next line.

Comment: @PaulvandenDool That does not accord with my experience: I find it rather pleasant to read danluu.com for instance, probably because of the content… or for that matter [Project Gutenberg books with really large line widths](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/3070/3070-h/3070-h.htm). So I expect that the effect (eyes getting frustrated and tired) is either too small to notice, or varies with the population. How good (sample sizes, reproducibility etc.) is the science behind that claim, do you know?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR [This article sums it up nicely and gives some sources](http://uxmovement.com/content/how-margins-and-line-lengths-affect-user-reading/). I do have to admit that they say the most recent study says 95 characters to be the optimal length for reading speed. But 95 was the largest line length the study offered. Would 262 characters like on Danluu.com (on my 15" macbook) be better or worse? I can't say for sure. It is funny to note that most people find it more pleasant to read shorter line text like the studies say, unlike you.

Comment: @PaulvandenDool Thanks, very interesting. It's also funny that "some users reported that they felt like they were reading faster at 35 CPL. But that condition actually resulted in the slowest reading speed" — UX has to optimize for both user preference and user outcomes I guess, and they may actually be different. Who knows, I may be experiencing more eye strain in one case, but perceiving it as more in the other!

Comment: @ Paul van den Dool: 256 characters?  That's about 2X the width of my display with a comfortably-readable text size.  So is it one of those sites where each paragraph becomes a single line, and you have to scroll right & left to read?

Comment: @jamesqf I can answer for that: it's a site with basically no CSS, so each paragraph is as wide as your device width (this is the browser default). If you have a wide screen with a fullscreen browser window, you can see for yourself. No horizontal scrolling required. Looks fine on mobile too (correspondingly fewer characters per line of course).

Comment: I think there might be some cultural differences involved too, see for example http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35281/does-culture-affect-ux-best-practises

Comment: What's the reason for not increasing the font size to fill the window width with 95 characters?

Comment: @gandalf3 how would cultural difference effect line length? Apart from the difference between left to right and right to left (arabic) reading patterns. Or weren't you talking about line length?

Comment: @acbabis I can't really substantiate any of this, but I don't think there isn't really a solid reason not to. I think it would be bold and innovative to have a website with huge letters on desktop. If I have to think of a reason not to, I would say because on big screen people would have to move their head to read (or sit back relatively far) and because it's not convention. When thinking about an article, people still think about an article on paper (in a mag or in a news paper). And there they use small lettering. Check out these http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2017/01/75-type-driven-sites/

Comment: @PaulvandenDool I was referring to the tendency described in the linked answer, of many Asian designs maximizing information density instead of US (and European?) tendency towards more minimalist designs. I intended to put that comment on the question, but I must've gotten lost (was on mobile at the time).

Comment: If your site primarily contains paragraphs of text, which your users want to read, this question is 100% correct - it is much easier to read prose when the line length is 50-60 characters per line, including spaces. Many studies have proved this, which is why most novels use this line length too. As for filling up the resulting white space left and right - that all depends on the business hosting the website.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Re "...each paragraph is as wide as your device width...", it's often much wider.  Unless it's picking up my 3-wide set of virtual screens as "device width".  In any case, why would a browser default to device width, and not to browser window width?

Comment: @jamesqf Yes I meant browser window width instead of device width sorry; I always use my browser windows at full screen so it was an easy mistake to make. All I meant was that, in the absence of any CSS limiting the width of paragraphs, the browser default is that they occupy the available area (browser window width I guess, minus the width of scrollbars etc), so it wraps at whatever your browser width is, with no horizontal scrolling. At least in the browsers I know. On desktop and mobile.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Here's a link to a page with the sort of one paragraph per line text I mean: http://www.tahoehorsetrails.com/spoonertomtrose.htm  Sites like this do the wide text on all PC browsers I remember - chiefly qupzilla (my current browser of choice), Opera, Firefox &c.  Interestingly, on an Android tablet it makes the text small enough to fit the screen width (and too small to read!), perhaps because I've never set a preferred font size.

Answer (score 78):

**There is a reasonable limit in the amount of information the user should see at once**.

If the view is filled with more information than the user can assimilate/understand it becomes overwhelming. [This will depend on the kind of content](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/104752/32130) and the way the information is displayed.

It is not a matter of leaving empty space, but of using the amount of space needed, not more.

To illustrate the point with your example:

[image]

As websites can make use of scroll, there is no need to put as much information as possible in a single screen.

[image]

Now, how to distribute the content?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Depending on the site the content might be centered or left aligned (this last one probably due to reading Left to Right). There is another alternative which is not to distribute the space in the boundaries of the containers, but instead inside the elements. This kind of layout might be useful if there are several columns inside the containers and there is a sidebar in each side. In other words, **it is worth if there are enough columns, and at some point the consistency of each element (each row) will start to break due to the information being too far apart**. And when we reach that point we are back to continue adding that empty space in any of the previous ways.

[image]

Comment: Why make users scroll extra if they don't need? True, you are able to scroll, yet it is still more work for users. A lot of times it's much easier if you see more information at once.

Comment: I think it has to do with overwhelming the user with content as well. If a website would utilize my full 27'' screen at 1920x1080, filling it with SO questions or news articles, I would be absolutely overwhelmed. Not to mention it's a lot more uncomfortable to read things at the edges or corners of your screen. Compare it to the standard now, where you can keep your focus at a small area in the middle of the screen, and instead of moving your focus all the time, you can move the content that's in your focus with the scrollwheel.

Comment: @Alvaro Also, I thought of this question after I saw the discussion about the [new SO top-bar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343247). One of the main problems there is that their isn't enough space, so I wouldn't say they are using the amount of space needed and don't need more space.

Comment: For smaller screens, the site can easily be made responsive to go to a single line then. For larger screens though, it still seems to be just a waste of space.

Comment: @TotZam Take a look to [this link](http://uxmyths.com/post/2059998441/myth-28-white-space-is-wasted-space).

Comment: @Alvaro I fully agree that whitespace in general is crucial, yet my question is just asking about the huge space on the sides of some pages. If you get rid of that space, you then have the room to add more space around and between the actual elements.

Comment: @TotZam it is because of the amount of information shown. Your screenshots might fit double the content, but then it would probably be overwhelming to analyse all at once.

Comment: @IvoCoumans I hear that too much content can get overwhelming, yet the sites I listed that don't use extra side whitespace seem okay.

Comment: @TotZam , in the cases you post (at least in [the Google one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lp7TZ.jpg)) there is a limit too. The thing might be that the limit depends on the content and is subjective to each website, though.

Comment: There are ways to make use of more space without displaying a crazy amount of information. You can space out the actual elements more or make font sizes a drop larger. The UX site example that you added definitely is overwhelming, since there are so many separate tiny pieces of information, yet I've seen sites use the space well. I think SE would still look okay if the main content was left in the middle and a side bar of information was added to each side with more spacing between all the elements.

Comment: @TotZam there is certainly a limit where things start to look overwhelming, but this limit is subjective.

Comment: @Ivo Coumans: Also I have other things on my screen besides the browser window, so I don't want it taking up the full width of the screen.

Comment: @TotZam I don't know if it's the case, but I get the feeling you are assuming everybody would use the browser maximized even on wide monitors... Is that so?

Comment: @TotZam I edited the answer to address the concern on why empty space around the containers and not put it inside instead.

Comment: @Alvaro The new screenshots do make your point clearer. Thanks for taking the time to write a great response.

Comment: Honestly, I wish websites had an option to set the design as in your first screenshot. Not literally like that, but just lots of info and links filling the screen.

Comment: @rwols It might be useful if you have experience with the website and know where you want to look at. The problem is if a user arrives to such website and has no clue of where is the important content, there is a high chance he will simply run away.

Comment: @TotZam That's not what I feel like. I'd rather see information bit by bit from most important to least important than be presented with a blanket of information that I will have to try to make sense of.

Answer (score 18):

### Academic studies on white space

Yes, white space is used to **increase readability and reduce visual clutter** [[1]](http://usabilitynews.org/reading-online-text-a-comparison-of-four-white-space-layouts/), [[2]](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Constantinos_Coursaris/publication/269639066_Web_Aesthetics_and_Usability/links/565cbb5b08ae4988a7bb8090.pdf).

The more objects are on the screen the more the eye and the brain has to process [[3]](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v390/n6657/full/390279a0.html). **With empty space we reduce the required attentional resources to process the page**. However, too much (more than 50%) of it can have a negative effect on readability and user satisfaction [[4]](http://usabilitynews.org/finding-information-on-the-web-does-the-amount-of-whitespace-really-matter/).

> Does the whitespace make sites compatible with certain screen sizes?

Not really. If the page has no white space (and is stacked with content), when designing for different resolutions it will become a huge problem how to position all elements of the page for the different resolutions.

> Does leaving the space help make sites mobile friendly?

Well not exactly. On mobile resolutions you can notice there is not that much white space. They have different layout structure because of the limited screen space available on mobile phones.

---

References:

[1] Chaparro B. et al., *Reading Online Text: A Comparison of Four White Space Layouts*, 2004

[2] Coursaris C. and Kripintris K., *Web Aesthetics and Usability: An Empirical Study of the Effects of White Space*, 2012

[3] S. Luck and E. Vogel *The capacity of visual working memory for features and conjunctions*, 1997

[4] Bernard M., Chaparro B., & Thomasson R., *Finding Information on the Web: Does the Amount of Whitespace Really Matter?*, 2000

Comment: So are you saying it is better to leave a huge white space at the sides, rather than filling up the page and adding more space between the actual elements?

Comment: Maybe the monitor should be a big ball that you stick your head inside, and there should be content everywhere you look. Add good speakers and some scent and voila! Immersive websites! Now, just carry it in your pocket. Doh!

Comment: @TotZam Nope, both approaches are valid.

Comment: @TotZam Not generally. But how would you add all that space from the sides in between the elements here and still preserve visual coherence?

Answer (score 18):

As a web developer speaking for the sites I've made: we didn't design for large width display. And white space is what defaults when you scale the browser width up (or whatever the CSS background color is).

The costs of designing and developing a responsive and scalable website across desktop and mobile are already quite high. Our analytics show that 90%+ of our users view our site in <1400 px wide resolution.

At the end of the day, it's not worth it to spend the time and money designing and implementing for the <10% of users who browse our sites at >1400px wide resolution.

Related: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/what-is-the-standard-width-for-a-website-in-pixels

Comment: -1 @y3sh How this answers the question? You are talking about your target audience, like its the same with every other site. And the question is not what resolutions your users have or how costly is to design for mobile and desktop.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov the question is "Why do many sites leave half of each webpage empty?" And the answer that it's not for usability or UI reasons but for cost is a reasonable one. Especially with many people having mobile devices, it's not worth it to develop any Website UI for a few tablet or Widescreen user if they only makeup a small fraction.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful But y3sh talks about his user group and how it is not feasible to design for desktop if you have only 10% desktop visitors. The argument may be valid but for other question. He does not even mention white space.

Comment: @KristiyanLukanov I assumed it was widely known that white space is the default when you don't design for something on a webpage (or black space if your body background  is black, etc). I can add it.

Answer (score 6):

Because some people browse like me, with the monitor turned 90°.

[image]

**Other people are on tablets, phones, and Win 3.11 with 640*480 resolution and 8 bit colour.** The best websites are generally designed to look readable on all devices, not look great on any particular device.

Comment: I wonder if designers really have rotated screens in mind, but this is still an interesting idea.

Comment: @TotZam: My point wasn't rotated screens per se, but rather differing screen widths. See the text below the image.

Comment: @TotZam - probably the designers simply had the still-quite-common 4:3 aspect ratio screens in mind, rather than the 16:9 screen aspect ratio yours appears to be.  I do most of my web viewing on a 1280x1024 monitor (I find a 17" 4:3 monitor fits nicely on my desk alongside a 24" 16:9 as the primary display) and stack exchange's design works nicely on that.  There's a bit of whitespace on either side (about 90 pixels), but not so much as it appears wasted, and seems like a natural amount to have to me, so I *think* this is the resolution the site was optimized for.

Comment: Your example shows that your vertical screen is still some pixels too narrow (or the website is a few pixels too wide), as there is a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: My point wasn't that "my preferred screen layout is the target audience" but rather "**no particular** screen layout is the target audience.

Comment: @dotancohen Sorry, my comment wasn't meant as a criticism to your answer, just an observation that it still doesn't quite fit. (I'm also using one of my monitors in portrait mode, though usually not for websites, but for my IDE.)

Comment: Or in other words, because wide screens only work well for movies, not text. Fortunately the tablet makers are finally realising this; maybe desktop screen makers will realise this too.

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer - I have two screens - one in portrait and one in landscape, so depending where I drag the browser window...

Comment: 8 bit color was a really fancy setup in the days of Windows 3.11. Compare [What algorithm did Microsoft use to dither colour in early versions of Windows?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1887/357) on [retrocomputing.se].

Answer (score 4):

If the content is naturally that wide, then by all means make the page wider. So for example, a large table, would be much more usable if it used as much width as it needed, than by being cramped in a narrower column. I have used google docs spreadsheet full screen in the past, and that's useful.

But as others have said though, there's a limit to how long lines of text should be before they get hard to read. It's because it becomes difficult to find the start of the next line as your eye moves back to the left, so text columns should only be so wide.

Another argument for not having wide webpages is that I didn't buy a huge monitor just so I could see more of any one website. As screens get larger people become less likely to maximise windows, so the browser isn't that wide anyhow.

I bought a huge monitor (actually, two huge monitors side by side, and I'd have more if my machine would drive them) so that I could have multiple windows, browsers, editors, etc side by side. That way I don't have to constantly switch between apps, I can just glance from one to the other, which makes things much more efficient. This is likely most true for sites like stackexchange, which are often used in work contexts, where people are working on other things at the same time. It's almost certainly much less important for entertainment sites.

So, as with any usability question, think about the context your users are working in. Is your site the only thing they're looking at, or is it just one part of what they're doing? Can you really be sure of that? Have you logged that info for example?

Even if it is the only thing they're doing, there's still no point in putting things on screen unless they actually serve some purpose. Otherwise they're just noise which detracts from the thing you actually want them to be looking at (or indeed, they want to be looking at). So, if it's genuinely useful then go ahead. But don't just fill space for the sake of it.

Comment: I like how this answer shows a use for both designs and gives examples of when it would be appropriate to go full screen and when it is excessive and better to stay small.

Answer (score 3):

That design is easily found and changed using bootstrap, the example is here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid

Simple answer for the UI is that paragraph width is comparable to the amount of unforced movement an eye can make from left to right - also it's comparable to a sheet of paper.

Normally the readable area of a paragraph should be no wider than an average sized hand.

Comment: So are you saying that it is always better to leave space and never fill up a whole screen? In what cases would you say I should use each design?

Comment: Paragraph or article text should always meet the criteria above. Layouts can use fluid containers but can contain fixed containers to support paragraph readability. Also fixed containers are helpful to support the invisible "guidelines" of the layout when using jumbotrons, h1's, large ad placements, etc.

Comment: Also it isn't about space, mostly about left to right width for readability. I'd say the white space should be kept blank and especially for bootstrap usability, there is no native way to fill the white space. You'll also notice the side margins shrink and respond to the viewport to conform to the "readability requirements" so it's not consistently available space.

Answer (score 2):

I was really surprised to see this question and the interest for the subject. This seems to me to be part of the old debate around the question "Is white space wasted space?"

I think this is a myth and there are a lot of arguments that sustain the idea that white space is the key to successful design.

The most important argument for limit the width of the main block of content and have **layout white space** is it makes the design more usable and helps users **focus** on the most important elements. I can tell you from experience I simply leave those websites with so much info in a page that I have that feeling I will never find what I need. It is exhausting to see information all over the screen and I don't understand how I could focus on the middle column with text on the left side and the right side.

I know this is a little subjective, but on the page with a lot the info in the page, I have the feeling the developers didn't want to spend more time to add a button with "more" or synthesize what is important. It feels like a punishment and it feels cheap.

White space helps to:

- focus on the most important content;
- improves reading comprehension;
- create the look and feeling of minimalism and elegance.

In this article, [Why White Space Is Crucial To UX Design](https://www.fastcodesign.com/3046656/why-white-space-is-crucial-to-ux-design), I found an interesting opinion:

> White space has been proven to increase comprehension up to 20%.(...)
>
> White space helps create mental maps.(...)
>
> The power of white space comes from the limits of human attention and
> memory

Update: To be more specific, the alternative to having margins on the left and on the right is to have more columns or have a main box with a bigger width.

The problem with the first option is that it is hard to prioritize the important information and with the second one is it is hard to read a text with a big width.

A good argument to limit the width of a column is presented [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/ideal-column-width-for-paragraphs-online) and this reference is important to be mentioned:

> Is there an ideal line length for content?
>
> To quote a passage from
> “Web Style Guide – Basic design principles for creating web sites”.
>
> The ideal line length for text layout is based on the physiology of
> the human eye…
>
> At normal reading distance the arc of the visual field
> is only a few inches – about the width of a well-designed column of
> text, or about 12 words per line. Research shows that reading slows
> and retention rates fall as line length begins to exceed the ideal
> width, because the reader then needs to use the muscles of the eye and
> neck to track from the end of one line to the beginning of the next
> line. If the eye must traverse great distances on the page, the reader
> is easily lost and must hunt for the beginning of the next line.
> Quantitative studies show that moderate line lengths significantly
> increase the legibility of text.
>
> Web Style Guide – Basic Design Principles for Creating Website Patrick
> J. Lynch and Sarah Horton 2nd edition, page 97.

Comment: My question is not asking about whitespace in general. I agree that whitespace is critical to good design. My question is asking specifically about the whitespace on the sides of the page.

Comment: @TotZam I understood. Maybe I didn't write this in every sentence, but I also augmented why layout white space is important and why having multiple columns or a lot of content make the user feel uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2):

I would say field of vision plays a role. You can easily read a piece of paper and the width of the website is about the same size. This way you don't have to move your head as much in the horizontal direction while reading or parsing the page.

Also even if you tried to reduce the whitespace, then how would you do it? 
It's not necessarily easy. 
Most of the questions are already quite short. 
2 Pages next to each other ? 
How would that work with inifinte scroll or scrolling in general ?

Comment: This is a good point.  I've commented above that the site seems optimized for 4:3 screens, but it's worth pointing out that 4:3 aspect ratio was (AIUI) originally selected as what we can comfortably see all of without needing to shift our vision from place to place.  The more modern 16:9 screens are derived from cinematographic formats that were designed to intentionally place action in peripheral vision in order to create a more immersive feel.

Answer (score 1):

I have read all the answers above, but didn't see anywhere any mention to responsive issues that might occur.

Although I still don't get the 'mobile first' design, if you are to design a web application responsive, the same content has to look nice from 320px up to.. whatever. I am mainly working with dashboards, so, a lot of space is needed, but most of the times I still can't stretch content so much that would responsively look good along all the resolution tiers.

Always keep in mind that the longer the container width is, that content will be stacked in smaller resolution tiers and the larger the height of the content block in those resolutions. For example a single line of text in a 1920px width container, consumes 140px of height on a mobile screen view - that's 30% of a small phone screen height and that's excluding browser UI. I am currently on a 21:9 3440x1440px screen. Imaging having items that stretch from side to side on my screen.. Let alone that sometimes I have to turn my head to see desktop from side to side! :D

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/cjj1Ln36/1/

By experience, anything more than 1400px is an overkill especially for rich content, eg combination of a title, text and a chart. Usually, the logical thing to do in higher resolutions, is to break content in columns, however, depending on the resolution and by experience, these columns end up being either too barren or too dense depending on the resolution. It is also highly unlikely that two blocks of code will contain the same content - likely impossible to predict in dynamic websites, so the content of a column might be dense and the other sparse.

For photo-rich websites, things are even worse.

a) If photos use full container width of 1400px, but have to keep a common ratio, like 4:3, then it would most likely occupy all of the screen's height and most likely exceed it.

https://jsfiddle.net/mg965au8/1/

b) If the photo is used on the side of the text, then going from a resolution of 1400px down to a resolution where the photo makes sense to sit above the text (eg > 768px), most probably the content would start too sparse and will probably exceed the image's height while shrinking. I have created a fiddle to illustrate the issue. Try expanding from a low resolution up to the maximum 1400px (imagine without a container!). Does it look nice to all browser widths? Probably not.

https://jsfiddle.net/2xnt3mk2/

Also, what all the others above said - too overwhelming, etc

Comment: **but didn't see anywhere any mention to responsive issues that might occur.** Take a look at the accepted answer, it took me quite some time to write it and consider what you mention in your answer, I even included images!

Comment: @Devin but didn't write this to oppose your wonderful answer. What I am describing is the fact that designers are unable to fill the whole screen because of responsive issues - content that has to fit in small screen sizes cannot be stretched infinitely - after some point it becomes too sparse and too ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Especially in text-heavy websites, a narrow column of text is more pleasant to read than a full-width wall of text. Also, if the text is not a novel, you will find that more than half the lines of text don't reach full width so it creates an unpleasant and uneven "text blot".

Think about how text is displayed in a (physical) novel vs. a dictionary. Dictionaries are usually displayed in two columns. It allows the reader to focus better on what is being read because it's important. It's not so important to retain all the words in a novel, as well as not as difficult because we assume the reader is already interested in the story.

In short: humans have poor attention spans and retain focus better if given little information at a time.

Comment: There are already several answers on this question that basically say the same thing as this. Can you expand and state what differenciates your answer to the others that mention line-length? If everyone just answers with the same thing that that negates the usefulness of the post as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on a content type, its size and on a distance of a user from the screen.

For videos, dashboards with large photos or presentations - full screen is the best option.

For the text content and small to middle pics it is critical to take a comfortable perception field into account.

How wide would be a comfortable perception field without a need to move your eyes from left to right for a normal PC or notebook with 50 to 65 cm (20 to 26 inches) distance to a sitting user?

Eyes are too valuable and get tired quickly, so people prefer to fix the extensive degrees of freedom from 2-D motion to 1-D motion and scroll the page vertically and let the eyes stay fixed in their position.

Scrolling the page vertically is easier for people, as moving the eyes back and forth from left to right and additionally re-fixing the vertical position of the current/next content. Some content can simply be lost, if it is placed outside the main perception field.

As a result the overall visual impression from a page may suffer.