# Dealing with too much white space

Tags: white-space, space

I am working on some wireframes for an app. The app has a lot of short flows that usually require filling two inputs fields or have a small FAQ as seen in the examples below. I tried looking the internet for some suggestion but nothing helps.

I`m looking for some standards or best practices.

I tried a few variations but all seem off in my opinion.

**1. Aligned left small container.**

**2. Full width container and content**

**3. Full width container with center content**

**4. Center content**

[image: smaller container aligned left]

[image: full width]

[image]

[image]

Comment: related https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/124228/what-is-the-best-max-width-content-container-in-a-website

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is where to align the container, why using a container?

[image: Container]

The containers are used to arrange the information by putting a limit frame, but sometimes they are visual noise, among other reasons, for which you indirectly state in your question.

In your case there are four containers (five if there's a header):

1. the one on the web
2. the FAQ container
3. the question container
4. the answer container

Arranging these four related containers can be a tedious and meaningless job if the result will always be visual noise.

Comment: Hello, Good answer. The problem is not where to align the container but where to align the content when there is small content on a 1920 resolution that leaves a lot of white space everywhere as I have a lot of pages with very little content.

Comment: If the title *FAQ* is aligned to the left, the content must also be aligned to the left regardless of the content extension. Without a visual container this will be not a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow this very website you'll see that the left menu + container are centered, with white space around it.

On the other hand, looking at the [Blender manual website](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/) you'll see the layout follows your first option (Aligned left small container). I've seen both examples in many different websites.

I'd say it will be a matter of preference, as long as you don't stretch the container too much, which will [make lines more difficult to read](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/ideal-column-width-for-paragraphs-online). Your content doesn't need to stretch all the way to the edges of the screen on all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest testing a few variants with some of your users to see if they have a preference.

Regardless of whether you want to test or not, I suggest you create a few variations with a variety of content, short and long texts and view them at different screen sizes to give yourself a better idea of what people will get to see. Then make a decision on what looks best overall. If that means at certain length of content it's less visually appealing, I doubt the user experience will suffer from it.