# Should you flex items throughout all the viewport on desktop?

Tags: viewport

I've been noticing many popular websites often don't span items throughout all the viewport on desktop screens. For instance, Google:[image]

I noticed this recently while building a website. I was flexing the card items throughout all the viewport, but I realized that by reducing the width of the parent div (say to 70vw), it was "easier" for the eyes to look to the cards in order, as opposed to when the items flex throughout all the viewport and you need to look from the total left of the screen to the right (more eye movement).

Is there a resource that talks about this? I don't know what's the technical term of this technique, but I'm sure there is UX design intention here.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best max-width content container in a website?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/124228/what-is-the-best-max-width-content-container-in-a-website)

Comment: @Nash Kind of. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

Two famous resources are: White Space and Gestalt

White Space: improve user focus
Gestalt: help you to groupping and managing information

You can read more here:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-white-space/

Comment: Can't upvote you because I don't have enough rep, but this is helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [white space considerations](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/form-design-white-space/), as mentioned by Juliano, one should also consider line length for readable paragraphs.

The common rule is to  try and not make readable text too many characters per line. Good length seems to be around 50-75 characters. [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#visual-presentation) seems to agree on 80 characters

Here are good articles about that:

- https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability
- https://www.rocketspark.com/blog/post/225/How-important-is-line-length-for-great-web-design/